# Upload multiple photos to Facebook using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, titanium, titanium-mobile

In My Titanium Mobile Application I am trying to post multiple image to Facebook album. But for me single image upload works fine but multiple image does not. Here is my sample code.
Thanks in Advance. My Titanium SDK 1.7.5 and my platform ios

```
var media = [];
var file1 = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(currIamge1);
var blob1 = file1.read();
var file2 = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(currIamge2);
var blob2 = file2.read();
    media.push({'message': 'House1', 'picture': blob1}); 
    media.push({'message': 'House2', 'picture': blob2}); 
var path = album_id+'/photos'; 
Titanium.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath(path, media, 'POST', function(e){
    if (e.success) {
        alert("Success!  From FB: " + e.result);
    } else {
        if (e.error) {
            alert(e.error);
        } else {
            alert("Unkown result");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: see answer here http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/132333/upload-multiple-photos-to-facebook-album